# registration multistep in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

The standard form of drupal all fields are in the same page, I want to change so that when the user is registered and register on stages:

- step 1 (email and password)
- step 2 (name and surname )
- step 3 (picture)

  step by step complete

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: will you want all fields mandatory for registration?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/ms_ajax_form_example  or use field group with vertical tabs to show least fields